# Liferay - AutoLogin + Authenticator - Get Credentials From Request Header

Tags: liferay

I need help with Liferay Autologin and Custom Authentication.

My goal is to get credentials from header (populated by differents authentication framework) and then autologin. I have also to call some services when user login.

I've read some docs (also that one at http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Developing+a+Custom+Authentication+System) but still I doesn't understand.

I've done a hook with portal.properties:

```
auto.login.hooks=it.mypackage.filter.AutoLoginFilter
```

and the class:

```
public class AutoLoginFilter implements AutoLogin {


    public AutoLoginFilter() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] login(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse arg1) throws AutoLoginException {
        String[] credentials = new String[] { "test@liferay.com" };
        return credentials;
    }
}
```

In the example class AutoLogin I suppose to return just the username (I doesn' need to verify other credentials).

Then I create a ext with portal-ext.properties:

```
auth.pipeline.pre=it.mypackage.auth.MyAuthenticator
auth.pipeline.enable.liferay.check=false
```

and the authenticator:

```
public class MyAuthenticator implements Authenticator {

    private static Log _log = LogFactory.getLog(SwaFiamAuthenticator.class);

    @Override
    public int authenticateByEmailAddress(long companyId, String emailAddress, String password,
            Map<String, String[]> headerMap, Map<String, String[]> parameterMap) throws AuthException {
        return authenticate();
    }

    @Override
    public int authenticateByScreenName(long companyId, String screenName, String password,
            Map<String, String[]> headerMap, Map<String, String[]> parameterMap) throws AuthException {
        return authenticate();
    }

    @Override
    public int authenticateByUserId(long companyId, long userId, String password, Map<String, String[]> headerMap,
            Map<String, String[]> parameterMap) throws AuthException {
        return authenticate();
    }

    protected int authenticate() {
        _log.debug("returning SUCCESS");
        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

What I expect from the code is:

Every user entering the portal is automatically authenticated without seeing any login page, and is recognized as user "test@liferay.com"

What I get:

AutoLoginFilter.login is called, but the user is still redirected to login page.
MyAuthenticator never called (it's called only if I remove AutoLogin-hook and 
remove also auth.pipeline.enable.liferay.check=false property).

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The returned array must contains at first the userId, something like this must work:

```
            String[] credentials = new String[3];
            credentials[0] = userId;
            credentials[1] = "undefined";
            credentials[2] = Boolean.FALSE.toString();
```

the userId you can find in Control Panel -> Users ->...

or (better way) load it programmaticaly with `UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByEmailAddress(companyId, emailAddress);`

the `auth.pipeline` is not needed for this approach.

Comment: Thanks Mark: 
Where I cant find documentation about the
String[] credentials = new String[3];
            credentials[0] = userId;
            credentials[1] = "undefined";
            credentials[2] = Boolean.FALSE.toString();

What is the third parameter set to false?
There are other parameters?

Comment: Similar, to much other things, I view such things in liferay source. Second parameter is the password, and the last parameter is the password validation. When last parameter is set to 'false', then the password is irrelevant.